# Add/Remove button Ajax only show one

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 buttons with this ajax and they both show on the page,how can i make it that only Add to favorites button is shown and when i click it the Remove From Favorites button takes it place ?

```js
function Fav(gameId) {
  var url = '@Url.Action("AddToCollection", "UserCollection")';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      gameId: gameId,
    },
  });
};

function UnFav(gameId) {
  var url = '@Url.Action("RemoveFromCollection", "UserCollection")';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      gameId: gameId
    },
  });
};
```

```html
<button class="btn-link" onclick="Fav(@Model.Id)"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>Add To Collection</button>

<button class="btn-link " onclick="UnFav(@Model.Id)"><i class="fa fa-heart-broken"></i>Remove From Collection</button>
```

Comment: When you are generating the html for the product, you need to check whether it is in Fav list or not and you need to show button based on that data.

Comment: And how can i do that ?

Comment: In your code, we can't see how you store that data on the database. You are probably storing that data in `UserCollection`. So, when iterating over that data, you can add a class to button's classlist. For example you can add `hidden` classname which will make the button `display: none;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

```js
const urls = {
  "AddToCollection": '@Url.Action("AddToCollection","UserCollection")',
  "RemoveFromCollection": '@Url.Action("RemoveFromCollection","UserCollection")'
}

function Fav(gameId, action) {
  $.ajax({
    url: urls[action],
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      gameId: gameId,
    },
  });
};

$(function() {
  const whichButton = "AddToCollection"; // set which one to show here using whatever method
  
  $(".btn-link[data-action="+whichButton+"]").show(); 
  $(".btn-link").on("click", function() {
    Fav(this.dataset.id, this.dataset.action)
    $(this).siblings().hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="favDiv">
  <button class="btn-link hide" data-action="AddToCollection" data-id=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>Add To Collection</button>
  <button class="btn-link hide" data-action="RemoveFromCollection" data-id=""><i class="fa fa-heart-broken"></i>Remove From Collection</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final result that i was looking for

```js
const urls = {
  "AddToCollection": '@Url.Action("AddToCollection","UserCollection",new { gameId = Model.Id })',
  "RemoveFromCollection": '@Url.Action("RemoveFromCollection","UserCollection",new { gameId = Model.Id })'
}

function Fav(gameId, action) {
  $.ajax({
    url: urls[action],
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      gameId: gameId,
    },
  });
};

$(function() {
  const whichButton = "AddToCollection"; // set which one to show here using whatever method

  $(".btn-link[data-action=" + whichButton + "]").show();
  $(".btn-link").on("click", function() {
    Fav(this.dataset.id, this.dataset.action)
    $(this).siblings().hide();
    $(this).siblings().show();
    $(".btn-link[data-action=" + whichButton + "]").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="favDiv">
  <button class="btn-link hide" data-action="AddToCollection" data-id=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>Add To Collection</button>
  <button class="btn-link hide" data-action="RemoveFromCollection" data-id=""><i class="fa fa-heart-broken"></i>Remove From Collection</button>
</div>
```